# Writing a python script to run another python script several times

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to use the Universal Reddit Scraper (https://github.com/JosephLai241/URS), a python script, to scrape the comments from several submissions in one subreddit. Currently it's set up to only scrape one submission at a time:

```
py urs.py -c https://www.reddit.com/r/antiwork/comments/rigxeg/ 0
```

I'd like to run this script in a loop, where the above URL is replaced by values in a CSV file for, say, 100 URLs.

Comment: Do you understand how to run python within a python file? What about loops? Opening and reading csv files? Just piece these together

Comment: It would probably be easier to modify https://github.com/JosephLai241/URS/blob/master/urs/Urs.py to call 'run' multiple times.  Just put a loop around the 'main' function and populate the variables from the CSV directly rather than from getenv